# i am trying to install ionic through cmd but i get the following error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm

[I am now learning ionic and cordova but get these error, I ma using window 10 please help me, I am studing want to leant that]

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
C:\Users\HP>node -v
v8.9.0

C:\Users\HP>npm -v
5.5.1

C:\Users\HP>npm install -g ionic
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request: ionic@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-04T07_56_31_200Z-debug.log
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBcJh.png

Comment: Works for me on node v6.10.1

Answer (score 0):

From official [Ionic Doc](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started/):

`npm install -g cordova ionic`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a bad proxy on your nodejs proxy settings.

first delete proxy settings by using these 2 commands :

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

Then retry. If it is not still working, this means that you are behing a proxy and you should configure it. 
Ask your network administrator for the right proxy settings (IP and PORT) and configure them this way :

```
npm config set http-proxy http://your_proxy_ip:port
npm config set https-proxy http://your_proxy_ip:port
```

This worked for me. Good luck.